# Turn on location function from an ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using this function to  `this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` to obtain the lat and long of the user, the problem is if the location is not "on" I do not get any response. I need to know how to show an alert to the user that the location is not turned on.

Also when the user turn the location on and goes back to the app, the location does not load.

I already search some info, but nothing seems to work.

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
```

I do not get any response because the location is not on.

Comment: If the user turns the location back on, you're going to have resubscribe. Also, there  cordova libraries to check for GPS permissions and ask the user to enable GPS permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          // "this" here in the weather service is seen however currentLocation is always ""
          this.currentLocation = position.coords;
          callback(position.coords);
        },
        (failure) => {
          if (failure.message.indexOf("Only secure origins are allowed") == 0) {
            alert('Only secure origins are allowed by your browser.');
```

Try this way you have to subscribe to the geolocation for position and failure on failure there are different error codes and error message that will help you understand why geolocation failed

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API#Geolocation_Live_Example

Check the above link

Comment: Yes I already tried this solution, but it only works on navigators, and since I am building an Ionic App, it doesn't work.